# How can I install multiple versions of a dependency in foundry?

Tags: solidity, foundry, import, forge

In [hardhat multiple versions of a dependency can be installed](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/can-you-use-two-different-openzeppelin-package-versions-in-one-hardhat-repo/31112) as follows in the `package.json`(assuming `yarn` is being used):

```
"@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.3.2",
"openzeppelin-contracts-solc-0.7": "yarn:@openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.2-solc-0.7",
```

If you want to use `v4.3.2` then you can `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/..."` and similarly if you want to use `v3.4.2-solc-0.7` then you can `import "openzeppelin-contracts-solc-0.7/..."`

How can this be achieved in foundry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install say the 2 versions of `@openzeppelin/contracts` stated in the question, they can be installed as follows:

```shell
# notice show openzeppelin-contracts-solc-0.7= is prepended to the dependency
# this will name the dependency "openzeppelin-contracts-solc-0.7" instead of the default name "openzeppelin-contracts"
forge install openzeppelin-contracts-solc-0.7=openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@v3.4.2-solc-0.7

# now install the latest version of openzeppelin-contracts as follows
forge install openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
```